# Lower and upper bound generic constraints on same wildcard

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

Let's assume the following class hierarchy:

```java
class A{}
class B extends A{}
class C extends B{}
class D extends C{}
```

In Java, it is possible to define wildcards with generics like this:

```java
List<? extends A> aOrDown;//A or any subtype of A
List<? super D> dOrUp;//D or any supertype of D
```

Is it possible to bind the same wildcard to both an upper and lower bound?

I would imagine something like this:

```java
List<? extends A super B> combined;
List<? extends A & super B> combined;
```

However, those seem to raise a compile-time error.

Is there any way to do bind a generic wildcard to a specific part of the class hierarchy?

<sub>I am interested whether this is possible in theory, I don't have a practical use-case for this.</sub>

Comment: From a type theory point of view, this looks sound to me as long as you don't do something like `? extends B & super A`. `combined` would act as a producer of `A` and a consumer of `B`, but this is not a feature of Java. I guess implementing this would make the compiler a lot more complicated - the criteria for determining assignment compatibility need to be completely revised. And I don't see much benefit this feature would bring anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Section 4.5.1 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1) specifies the syntax for generic wildcards:

> ```
> TypeArguments:
>   < TypeArgumentList >
> TypeArgumentList:
>   TypeArgument {, TypeArgument}
> TypeArgument:
>   ReferenceType
>   Wildcard
> Wildcard:
>   {Annotation} ? [WildcardBounds]
> WildcardBounds:
>   extends ReferenceType
>   super ReferenceType
> ```

In here, `WildcardBounds` is written in square brackets. In [Section 2.4 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-2.html#jls-2.4), it is explained that in this context, square brackets indicate optional elements that can be put only once:

> The syntax [x] on the right-hand side of a production denotes zero or one occurrences of x. That is, x is an optional symbol. The alternative which contains the optional symbol actually defines two alternatives: one that omits the optional symbol and one that includes it.

For bounded generic wildcards, this means that only one wildcard bound is permitted.